# C++ Design a struct of the data

Tags: c++

I have a data struct -

`{"BRAZIL", { {"IPHONE",{100,100} },{"IPOD", {65,100} } }`

I want to use operator `=` to save the data into a struct . I tried to design the struct like `map<string, vector<map<string, vector<int>>>>`,and use -

`price_stock["BRAZIL"] = { { "IPHONE", { 100, 100 } }, { "IPOD", { 65, 100 } } }`

But I failed to directly assign the data into struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a level of braces:

```
price_stock["BRAZIL"] = {
    { // first element in vector
        {"IPHONE", {100, 100}} // element in inner map
    },
    { // second element in vector
        {"IPOD", {65, 100}}    // element in inner map
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This question confuse me so long . I used to think the error because of my struct design.Thanks a lot!:)

Comment: @phoenixsxy You are welcome and I totally understand. With many nested types and initializer lists if's easy to miss one level. Just make a comment on each level when you assign like I did above and it usually becomes clear.

Comment: The method of initial is brilliant!Thanks again! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Below I have given a simple example on how to use a struct in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

struct prices {
  std::string title;
  int stock;
  int price;
};


int main ()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<prices> > priceMap;
    std::vector<prices> priceVec {{"IPHONE",100,100}, {"IPOD",65,100}};
    priceMap["Brazil"] = priceVec;

    for (auto& itemVector : priceMap) {
        for (auto& structItem : itemVector.second) {
            std::cout << structItem.title << ":" << structItem.price << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the second integer means the stock of the goods.Not the price.So I think they should be separated.

Comment: Why do you think it should be separated? Isnt the stock associated with the product? Of course you can rename it as stock instead of price if thats what you meant?

Comment: Maybe I don't describe clearly. The two number is about two attributes of the goods like "IPHONE". The first one is the price ,the second one is the stock.I see your code splice them together as double.

Comment: Got it @phoenixsxy. Let me update the code :) And I think rather than using a map, a struct is faster :)